# Являются ли слова "одеяло" и "одеться" однокоренными?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова, морфемный-разбор

В учебнике "Приключения в городе Грамотеев" для двуязычных детей есть такое задание: Найди однокоренные слова и соедини их стрелкой. Даны два столбика слов.

```
   1. чистый                          2. одеться
      дерево                             зеркальный
      одеяло                             торопиться
      зеркало                            деревянный
      торопливый                         отпуск
      отпустить                          чистота
```

По идее ребенок должен соединить пару слов "одеяло и одеться", но в словаре Тихонова в слове "одеяло" выделен корень "одеял", а в слове "одеться" корень "де".
То есть, эти слова не являются однокоренными?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 3):

> По идее ребенок должен соединить пару слов "одеяло" и "одеться", но в
>   словаре Тихонова в слове "одеяло" выделен корень "одеял", а в слове
>   "одеться" корень "де". То есть, эти слова не являются однокоренными?

Исторически ***одеяло*** связано с глаголом ***одевать***, но сейчас большинство словаристов как однокоренные эти слова не рассматривает.

Слово ***одевать*** в древнерусском языке звучало как *"одеяти"*, от него и было образовано слово ***одеяло***: *одея-**л**-о.*

Сейчас слова *"одеяти"* нет, производящая основа для  ***одеяла*** утрачена. А поскольку суффикс *"ял"* (с помощью которого можно было бы образовать слово *одеяло* от *одевать*) ни в одном другом слове не встречается, не выделяется он большинством словаристов  и в слове ***одеяло***  —  и *"ял"* и бывшая приставка *"о"* вошли в корень: ***одеял***-о.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Выше я написал:

> ...большинство словаристов как однокоренные эти слова не
>   рассматривает.

Большинство. Но не все.

К примеру, однокоренными (с корнем "де"),  слова ***одевать*** (***де***ть -> **о**-деть -> оде-**ва**-ть) и ***одеяло*** (***де***ть -> **о**-деть -> оде-**ял**-о) считаются в словаре [*Ширшов И.А. "Толковый словообразовательный словарь русского языка", М., 2004*]:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простите, а для чего вы упоминаете некий суффикс *ял*? Для простоты?

Comment: _Aer: "Простите, а для чего вы упоминаете некий суффик ял? Для простоты?"_ === Ну и уж Вы меня тогда простите: а каким словообразовательным элементом можно было бы связать _одевать_ и _одеяло_, если не "ял"?

Comment: я о том, стоит ли считать это одной морфемой: все-таки jа и л два совершенно разных суффикса.

Comment: Т. е. Вы считаете возможным словообразование какого-либо слова одновременным присоединением к производящей основе **двух** суффиксов?

Comment: Нет, я такого не говорил. Увидел ваше факсимиле: не лучшее решение с "ял", на мой взгляд. Еще больше путает. Ну да ладно.

Comment: slava, а как Вы думаете,  слово "одеяние" можно считать однокоренным с "одеялом", ведь у них одна производящая основа "одеяти"? И как его разбирать: о/де/яни/е?

Comment: _Arina: slava, а как Вы думаете, слово "одеяние" можно считать однокоренным с "одеялом"?_ ===  Если _одеяло_ считать производным от _одеть_ (т. е. если принять точку зрения Ширшова), то _одеяло_ и _одеяние_, безусловно, можно считать однокоренными. Но, повторюсь, большинство словаристов придерживаются другой точки зрения -- _одеяло_ считают непроизводным словом с корнем  _одеял_.

Comment: _Arina: ведь у них одна производящая основа "одеяти"?_ === Эта производящая основа была тогда, когда существовало само слова _"одеяти"_. Я же написал выше: _Сейчас слова "одеяти" нет, производящая основа для **одеяла** утрачена._

Comment: _Arina:  И как его разбирать: о/де/яни/е?_ === Вне зависимости от того, выделять ли в этом слове приставку или нет, суффикс в нём будет "яниj": оде(ть) -> оде-яниj-е.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос. По Тихонову - нет. 
Но ясно, что подход авторов учебника совсем не совместим с Тихоновым.

Взрослому-то тут объяснить - как нечего делать. С точки зрения Тихонова тут произошло морфемное переразложение. Жило-было слово с одним корнем, а потом "забыло" свое родство. И стал у него корень другой. Ну это еще понятно даже ребенку. А вот как быть с тем, что взрослые дяди и тёти еще могут между собой договориться.

> Корень: -одеял-; окончание: -о [Тихонов, 1996].
>
> Приставка: о-; корень > -де-; суффиксы: -я-л; окончание: -о [Кузнецова, Ефремова, 1986].

(Цитирую по Викисловарю). И ведь оба правы, Просто Тихонов исповедует статический поход (как есть, или по-умному "синхронистский"), а Кузнецова с Ефремовой - диахроничесчкий, рассматривая историю существования слова.

Единственное, что могу предложить: попытаться объяснить ребенку, что Тихонов немного упрощает, пусть даже по нему корень у слов разный, но они все равно однокоренные, если посмотреть вглубь.

*Вообще-то обычно я на стороне словаря и авторитетных источников, если учебник им противоречит, то тем хуже для учебника. Но тут-то интуитивно понятно, что Тихонов неправ. Ну вполне же продуктвная парадигма: мыть-мыло (чем моют), забирать - забрало (чем забирают), бить - било, покрывать- покрывало, одевать(одеять) - одеяло... Не стоило бы оригинальничать.*

Answer (score 1):

МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ, что эти слова можно считать однокоренными по определению (хотя этот вопрос сложный и часто приходится сталкиваться с такими проблемами; неудивительно, что решаются они по-разному).

Возьмем определение из Википедии: Однокоренные слова — слова  с одинаковым корнем, разных частей речи или одной и той же части речи, но с разными приставками и суффиксами. Однокоренные слова связаны друг с другом отношением словообразования.

Попробуем сравнить слова покрывало и одеяло.

По/кры/ва/ть — по/кры/ва/л/о, о/де/ва/ть — о/де/я/л/о (вместо о/де/ва/л/о). Мы видим, что словообразовательные схемы одинаковые, только суффикс ВА изменил свою фонетическую форму (стал суффиксом Я, но с тем же значением). Возможно, это причина того, что слово одеяло сейчас не делят на морфемы.

Answer (score 1):

Эти слова восходят к одному и тому же глаголу *дѣти* (деть; класть, ставить) и исторически содержат один и тот же корень *дѣ*. В наши дни, согласитесь, глагола *дѣти* нет, да и слова *одеть* и *одеяло*, как кажется, не связаны с глаголом *деть*. В связи с устратой этой связи исторический корень *дѣ* в слове *одеяло* перестал выделяться и приставка с суффиксами "приросли" к нему. Давать такие задачки в учебнике, на мой взгляд, неправильно.

Comment: Aer, но скажите, пожалуйста, разве  корень ДЕ не считается связанным корнем? Например: на/де/ть, о/де/ть, раз/де/ть? Мы же так разбираем эти слова?

Comment: @Arina ну да, связанный. Разбираем: значение приставок в соответствующих глаголах вполне себе живо (раз — аннулировать результат действия, например). Другое дело, что *одеяло* уже слабо ассоциируется с глаголом *одеть*.

Comment: В современном языке - да, Вы правы. Отсюда, наверное,  и все проблемы.